# Can I use playwright for java from an AWS java lambda?

Tags: java, aws-lambda, playwright

I have started using playwright for java and I tried out something very simple locally like:

```
Playwright playwright = Playwright.create();
Browser browser = playwright.chromium().launch();
Page page = browser.newPage();
page.navigate("https://www.google.com");
logger.info(page.content());
```

This worked fine on my local environment but I want to be able to use playwright from an aws java lambda.
Is this possible?
When I deploy a simple java lambda with the above code in it and invoke the lambda from the aws console I get an error about:

> "Failed to install browsers"

and

> Error: Failed to launch chromium because executable doesn't exist at
> /home/user............/chrome-linux/chrome
> Try re-installing playwright with "npm install playwright".

In terms of the lambda, I am building it using a gradle build into a zip which is uploaded to aws.
Any advice on whether playwright for java can run from a java aws lambda and how to get it working?